# Jetpack compose otp Textfeild decorationbox last cell becomes smaller

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I am facing an issue where the last cell becomes small in certain devices like in the image.The last cell becomes smaller in width cause of lack of space

[image]

The jetpack compose code below

```
Column(modifier = modifier, horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
        BasicTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight(),
            value = TextFieldValue(otpText, selection = TextRange(otpText.length)),
            onValueChange = {
                onOtpTextChange(it.text)
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword),
            decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
                Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
                    repeat(otpCount) { index ->
                        CharView(
                            index = index,
                            text = otpText,
                            isError = isError,
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                    }
                }
            },
        )

@Composable
private fun CharView(
    index: Int,
    text: String,
    isError: Boolean
) {
    val isFocused = text.length == index
    val char = when {
        index >= text.length -> ""
        else -> text[index].toString()
    }
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(50.dp)
            .height(60.dp)
            .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.large)
            .border(
                1.dp, when {
                    isFocused -> Orange
                    else -> Gray
                }, RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
            )
            .padding(top = 10.dp),
        text = char,
        style = TextStyle(
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 28.sp,
            letterSpacing = 0.sp,
            color = Color.Black
        ),
        color = Color.Black,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Main Function**

```
 @Composable
    fun OTPTextField(
    value: String,
    length: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    boxWidth: Dp = 50.dp,
    boxHeight: Dp = 50.dp,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions(),
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
) {
    val spaceBetweenBoxes = 8.dp
    BasicTextField(modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(),
        value = value,
        singleLine = true,
        onValueChange = {
            if (it.length <= length) {
                onValueChange(it)
            }
        },
        enabled = enabled,
        keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
        keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
        decorationBox = {
            Row(
                Modifier
                    .size(width = (boxWidth + spaceBetweenBoxes) * length, height = boxHeight),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
            ) {

                repeat(length) { index ->
                    val colorr =
                        if (index == value.length) LocalCustomColorsPalette.current.OtpBorderSelectedColorColor else LocalCustomColorsPalette.current.OtpBorderUnSelectedColorColor
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(boxWidth, boxHeight)
                            .border(
                                1.dp,
                                color = colorr,
                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp)
                            ),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = value.getOrNull(index)?.toString() ?: "",
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
                            color = LocalCustomColorsPalette.current.textColor
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        })
}
```

**Function Calling**

```
var text by remember {
            mutableStateOf("")
        }
        OTPTextField(
            text,
            4,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .align(CenterHorizontally)
        ) {
            text = it
            if (text.length == 4) {
                focusManager.clearFocus()
            }
        }
```

Try this one help to resolve your error.